# If you push an object at a constant velocity is the net force zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I was just thinking that if I were to push an object with a constant applied force forward (causing the object to have a constant velocity of $X\ \mathrm{m/s}$) [F] on a frictionless surface, how can the net force on my water bottle be zero according to Newton's Second Law?

[image: graph of velocity versus time, showing a line starting at the origin and increasing in velocity until 5 seconds, then flat at all later times]

From 5s onward -> no acceleration.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newton's second law states that $$F = m a.$$ If you are pushing with a constant velocity, the change in velocity is zero. Because acceleration is equivalent to the change in velocity, acceleration is 0. This means that the net force is 0. Keep in mind that, if the object is on a frictionless surface, once it is accelerated to the velocity, the push will not affect it. The applied force will not matter because of inertia. Thus, no forces are acting on the object and the second law holds. I hope you understand this and it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your graph, for the first 5 seconds the net force applied to your bottle is per Newton’s second law $F=ma$ where $m$ is the mass of the bottle and the acceleration is $a=X m/s^2$, at which time the velocity reaches $X m/s$. Then you stopped pushing it or encountered an equal and opposite force of some kind and the net force became zero since $a=0$, and the bottle continues on at constant velocity of $X m/s$ per Newton’s first law.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would like to stress another aspect that the previous (correct) answers do not explicitly mention:

After the point t=5s the bottle and your “pushing apparatus” happen to move in the same direction with the same speed. The distance between them (at their contact point) may be zero but it may as well be, say, 1 Millimeter without changing the situation.